# Move object from one position to another considering the colliders

Tags: unity, c#

I want to move object from one position to another but with one exception that the object should adjust its path according to colliders. The object is free to fly so it should consider colliders in its way and adjust its position accordingly. Currently I am doing it with `[MoveTowards][1]` function, lerp and coroutine but It ignore the collider and with it smoothly moved to another position. How should I intelligently adjust my path?

Comment: Can you show us the scenario? The way that a human avoids obstacles is different from the way a car avoids obstacles which is different from the way a bird avoids obstacles, so we need more details about the kind of path you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the obstacles are static, use a [NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMesh.html).

If the obstacles are dynamic, you can use another larger collider around your object to determine if some safe distance to an obstacle is reached. Then, you can modify your heading and continue.